# Why does SslStream.Read always set TcpClient.Available to 0, when NetworkStream.Read doesn't

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream, sslstream

I have a `TcpClient` client connected to a server, that send a message back to the client.

When reading this data using the `NetworkStream.Read` class I can specify the amount of bytes I want to read using the `count` parameter, which will decrease the `TcpClient.Available` by `count` after the read is finished. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.8):

> count `Int32`
>   The maximum number of bytes to be read from the current stream.

In example:

```cs
public static void ReadResponse()
{
    if (client.Available > 0) // Assume client.Available is 500 here
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[12]; // I only want to read the first 12 bytes, this could be a header or something
        var read = 0;

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        while (read < buffer.Length)
        {
            read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    // breakpoint
    }
}
```

This reads the first 12 bytes of the 500 available on the `TcpClient` into `buffer`, and inspecting `client.Available` at the breakpoint will yield (the expected) result of `488` (500 - 12).

Now when I try to do the exact same thing, but using an `SslStream` this time, the results are rather unexpected to me.

```cs
public static void ReadResponse()
{
    if (client.Available > 0) // Assume client.Available is 500 here
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[12]; // I only want to read the first 12 bytes, this could be a header or something
        var read = 0;

        SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

        while (read < buffer.Length)
        {
            read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    // breakpoint
    }
}
```

This code will read the first 12 bytes into `buffer`, as expected. However when inspecting the `client.Available` at the breakpoint now will yield a result of `0`.

Like the normal `NetworkStream.Read` the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.read?view=netframework-4.8) for `SslStream.Read` states that `count` indicates the max amount of bytes to read.

> count `Int32` 
>   A `Int32` that contains the maximum number of bytes to read from this stream.

While it does only read those 12 bytes, and nothing more I am wondering where the remaining 488 bytes go.

In the docs for either `SslStream` or `TcpClient` I couldn't find anything indicating that using `SslStream.Read` flushes the stream or otherwise empties the `client.Available`. What is the reason for doing this (and where is this documented)?

---

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686356/sslstream-equivalent-of-tcpclient-available) that asks for an equivalent of `TcpClient.Available`, which is *not* what i'm asking for. I want to know *why* this happens, which isn't covered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the SslStream might be reading large chunks from the underlying TcpStream at once and buffering them internally, for efficiency reasons, or because the decryption process doesn't work byte-by-byte and needs a block of data to be available. So the fact that your TcpClient contains 0 available bytes means nothing, because those bytes are probably sitting in a buffer inside the SslStream.

---

In addition, your code to read 12 bytes is incorrect, which might be affecting what you're seeing.

Remember that `Stream.Read` can return *fewer* bytes than you were expecting. Subsequent calls to `Stream.Read` will return the number of bytes read *during that call*, and not overall.

So you need something like this:

```
int read = 0;
while (read < buffer.Length)
{
    int readThisTime = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read);
    if (readThisTime == 0)
    {
        // The end of the stream has been reached: throw an error?
    }
    read += readThisTime;
}
```

Comment: I tried it using the method your provided, which yields the exact same results (Though as you said it is now protected against reading fewer bytes than expected). It still clears the `Available` after reading only 12 out of `n` bytes though.

Comment: I see. So what happens is that creating a `new SslStream` copies the available buffer of the `TcpClient.GetStream()` into it's *own* buffer, clearing the client's stream making it return 0.

Comment: @Remy Yes. I mean, it's not guaranteed that it reads the *whole* buffer: it just so happens that it's decided to read at least 500 bytes this time.

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading from a TLS stream, it *over-reads*, maintaining an internal buffer of data that is yet to be decrypted - or which *has* been decrypted but not yet consumed. This is a common approach used in streams especially when they mutate the content (compression, encryption, etc), because there is not necessarily a 1:1 correlation between input and output payload sizes, *and* it may be necessary to read entire frames from the source - i.e. you can't just read 3 bytes - the API needs to read the entire frame (say, 512 bytes), decrypt the *frame*, give *you* the 3 you wanted, and hold onto the remaining 509 to give you next time(s) you ask. This means that it often needs to consume more from the source (the socket in this case) than it gives you.

Many streaming APIs also do the same for performance reasons, for example `StreamReader` over-reads from the underlying `Stream` and maintains internally both a `byteBuffer` of bytes not yet decoded, and a `charBuffer` of decoded characters available for consuming. Your question would then be comparable to:

> When using `StreamReader`, I've only read 3 characters, but my `Stream` has advanced 512 bytes; why?

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation and comparison! Is this behavior documented somewhere, or more of an "implicit" thing that comes with dealing with encrypted streams? I wasn't able to find it in the docs about (ssl)streams, but may have been looking in the wrong places.

Comment: @Remy I would turn it around and say: where is it documented that consuming from a stream needs to consume only what is *exactly* required for the current call? what is *documented* is that if you wrap one stream with an `SslStream`, and keep reading: you'll eventually get all of the decrypted bytes. Any expectation you have beyond that is something that wasn't specified anywhere.